# How to upload photos to Instagram using web request

Tags: c#, android, vb.net, instagram, webrequest

My question is how to upload photos to Instagram using the web request ?
In my opinion, That can be done by capturing the web request sent by Instagram Application on Android device and write it in any desktop language like c# or vb.

I tried to connect Fiddler on desktop to my Android device but I couldn't
Note: I'm connected to MikroTik server with TP-Link access point router in my home.

Comment: I realize this question is from a while ago, but this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54472037/332578

Answer (score 2):

Short answer. you can't. Posting photos is not part of their public API

If you try to reverse engineer their private API, whatever account they detect posting without using an official Instagram app (I'm guessing they use some sort of signature) will get perma banned.

Anecdotal as this may be, I have seen people experiment with this and have had accounts banned within 20 minutes.

Comment: No, There is some way.
If you read my question I didn't say that I want to do it using their API. I want to do it using the "Web Request''
There's a web request sent by their application on android. If we got its link, headers and the POST parameters, We would be able to write a code in any language sending the same request with the same UserAgent of android devices.

Comment: What you are talking about is reverse engineering their app to work out how to access their PRIVATE API. Its still an API request no matter how you word it.

Comment: Is there another way like connecting the android device with Fiddler in PC throw wireless connection ?
If not, How can I reverse engineer their app ?

Comment: Not sure what Fiddler is I'm afraid. A few answers on the same question suggest using an android emulator like Bluestacks. I've tried Bluestacks in the past and found it to be an adware and malware laden mess thats then near impossible to uninstall.

Comment: Fiddler is a free web debugging tool that captures the web requests sent by PC, I tried many tutorials that shows how to connect it to android device. but I failed, not sure if that because I'm using MikroTik or not.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not going to help with reverse engineering the API as it is against Instagram's Usage Policy and I will not be held responsible for your (or anyone else's) account getting banned

Answer (score 2):

You can use InstaSharp from Codeusa with the risk of get banned:

https://github.com/Codeusa/InstaSharp